# Execute a logic once refreshApex is finished in LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience

Is there any way we can execute a logic once refreshApex() is completed?

Looks like refreshApex works asynchronously and I want to execute few lines of code once refreshApex() is completed.

Any suggestions?

In js

```
 @wire(getLstOfContactsWithRoles, { accId: '$accId', reload: '$reloadContacts' })
    wiredContactRoles(result) {
        this.wiredContactRoleResult = result;
        const { data, error } = result;
        if (data) {
            // This has Generic Code
        } else if (error) {
            ///
        }
    }


fetchContactRoles(){
    //Logic before Refresh
    refreshApex(this.wiredContactRoleResult);

    // I want to execte the below code only after refreshApex() is completely executed.
    alert('-RefreshApex Completed====>');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

refreshApex appears to return a Promise, according to the documentation. You can chain that Promise later:

```
refreshApex(this.wiredContactRoleResult)
  .then(result => alert('refreshApex completed!')
  .catch(error => alert('There was an error!');
```

Comment: This is really good to know that RefreshApex returns a Promise. This really worked for me.. Thanks a lot..!